# Is project gamification sustainable over time?

Tags: motivation, gamification

I haven't used project gamification so asking from a newby perspective.

I am interested in understanding how you manage and sustain this process **over time**:

- how do you measure the success and benefits of gamification throughout the project?
- is it common to have a surge of interest at the beginning and then see the enthusiasm drop? if so, how do you keep the momentum going (e.g. do you update or introduce new rewards on a regular basis)?
- most theories of motivation widely recognize that intrinsic rewards outweigh extrinsic ones, especially over time. How do you use gamification to keep people motivated long-term?

Answer (score 1):

I think only you know the answer to that based on your team make up and dynamics.  I am loathe to introduce any practice that I'm not prepared to sustain.  It makes introducing future practices (ones that I **am** prepared to practice long term) that much harder as teams have long memories.

You also have to be careful about how you approach it.  To some people this stuff if gimmickry, and an insult to their intelligence.  Others find it fun and behave accordingly.  I guess that goes back to the first point -- know your team and think about their likely reactions.

Comment: totally agree with you about being comfortable the team is receptive to this. In some ways I do find the stuff a bit gimmicky, but am trying to keep an open mind and was wondering if there are lessons learnt over time around the benefits and success of gamification.

Answer (score 1):

We have some projects using [GetBadges](http://getbadg.es) for more than a year (disclaimer: I'm co-founder of GetBadges).

The trick is to moderate your game accordingly and introduce some twist over time. If you base your gamification on human interactions and behaviours instead of 'game mechanics' like leaderboards and points it will be fresh for much longer.

It's also common for some 'players' to drop after the initial enthusiasm, but the ones that remain will get a big boost to productivity over a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you say you measure gamification...what kind of gamification did you try?
I try find also some answers in this area: [Gamification and Daily Scrum - anybody ever tried sth like this?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/13991/gamification-and-daily-scrum-anybody-ever-tried-sth-like-this).

Regarding measurement...if think doing anomynous surveys asking the team members about their opinion would be a way to find out...

Comment: Thanks for digging up this older question.  Couple of bits of advice; Answers should answer the question, not carry on a discussion; if you need the original poster to clarify details (e.g "what kind of gamification....") submit a comment, not an answer.  I appreciate the link, but to avoid link rot, best practice is to summarize the key features of the link and how they answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, I just did the pm.stackexchange-newby tour;)...I will try to consider this.